# How to recover outlook settings from backup?

Tags: backup, outlook

Before we sent the Vista machine off we backed up via the Migration Wizard and with MS Backup onto a portable drive.  When the machine came back with a new HDD we installed vista and ran MIG.  Some clown got the MIG process backwards and overwrote the data with the blank Vista profile.

Luckily we have a complete backup, files are back but nothing else is.  The most important part is Outlook.  Obviously just dropping the files into the profile is no good, what now?

Comment: So it's been five years now...  The real question should have been, how does one back up an Outlook profile, which I'm still not sure you can do.  Can't backup the passwords anyway.

Answer (score 2):

When I switch users mahcines I backup the .pst, located in

C:\Documents and Settings\userprofile\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook

Then, on the new machine, I setup an Outlook account with the users email address, password, etc.  Outlook will create a new .pst, which I overwrite with the old one.

Restart Outlook and you're good to go.

Comment: Yes, that's what we did in the end, but the real trick is getting the user settings.